# how to scrape Tripadvisor dynamically using scrapy and python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape TripAdvisor's reviews, but I cannot find the Xpath to have it dynamically go through all the pages. I tried `yield` and callback but the thing is I cannot find the xpath for the line that goes to the next page. I am talking about [This site](http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g297679-d300955-Reviews-Ooty_Fern_Hill_A_Sterling_Holidays_Resort-Ooty_Tamil_Nadu.html)

Here Is my code(UPDATED):

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapingtest.items import ScrapingTestingItem


class scrapingtestspider(Spider):
    name = "scrapytesting"
    allowed_domains = ["tripadvisor.in"]
    base_uri = "tripadvisor.in"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g297679-d300955-Reviews-Ooty_Fern_Hill_A_Sterling_Holidays_Resort-Ooty_Tamil_Nadu.html"]

    output_json_dict = {}
    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href').extract()
        items = []
        i=0
        for sites in sites:
            item = ScrapingTestingItem()
            #item['reviews'] = sel.xpath('//p[@class="partial_entry"]/text()').extract()
            item['subjects'] = sel.xpath('//span[@class="noQuotes"]/text()').extract()
            item['stars'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="rate sprite-rating_s rating_s"]/img/@alt').extract()
            item['names'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="username mo"]/span/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
            i+=1
            sites = sel.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href').extract()

            if(sites and len(sites) > 0):
                yield Request(url="tripadvisor.in" + sites[i], callback=self.parse)
            else:
                yield items
```

Comment: Don't you get an error in your code? I get an `IndexError` because the index of the sites is quite big...

Comment: Is that why or is it because the list only has 1 link in the list? I did get an error. But I dont think it shoud matter that there are 70 pages

Comment: I tested it out in scrapy shell and it looped through fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the URL behind Next why don't you try something like this:

```
next_url = response.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href).extract()
```

And then `yield` a Request with this URL? With this you get always the next site to scrape and do not need the line containing the numbers.

Recently I did something similar on tripadvisor and this approach worked for me. If this won't work for you update your code with the approach you are trying to see where it can be approved.

**Update**
And change your `Request` creation block to the following:

```
if(sites and len(sites) > 0):
    for site in sites:
        yield Request(url="http://tripadvisor.in" + site, callback=self.parse)
```

Remove the `else` part and `yield items` at the end of the loop when the method finished with every parsing.

Comment: getting an error, says that the list index is out of range. I tested the Xpath in scrapy shell and I too was only getting one site address. I will update my code above.

Comment: Also why is it a list, It says I cannot concant str and list thats why I have the `i+=1` and sites[i]

Comment: Your approach is a bit problematic with the list. You increase `i` but it has no relevance to the `sites` array. You can simply reach an out-of-bounds index with this approach. Look at the updated code -- which uses lists more properly.

Comment: WOW, thanks for that. It works like a charm. My internet bill is suffering lol

Comment: Last question, when I so `scrapy crawl scrapytesting -o output.json` only the first page info shows up. Could you guide me as to why that is, maybe it is the return

Comment: try to `yield item` instead of adding it to the `items` list. Then it should work and you can delete the list from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can only work if you make a list of urls you want to scrap in a .txt file.

```
class scrapingtestspider(Spider):
    name = "scrapytesting"
    allowed_domains = ["tripadvisor.in"]
    base_uri = "tripadvisor.in" 

    f = open("urls.txt")
            start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
            f.close()
```